# Make doesn't realize that it's done

Tags: makefile

This is my first ever post to stackoverflow.  It ought to be straightforward, but I have this problem whenever I try to write a makefile and I've never been able to figure out a satisfactory solution.  Apologies if there is already a solution somewhere on the site.  I couldn't find one.

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

1. Search my src directory for matching source files.
2. Compile the src code into a sandbox.

Here's my directory structure:

```
makefile
src1
    file1.src
    file2.src
src2
    file3.src
subfolder
    src3
        file4.src
        file5.src
```

And here's my makefile:

```
BUILDDIR := ./sandbox
SRC_DIRS := ./
SRCS     := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.src)
OBJS     := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/o., $(notdir $(SRCS) ) )

# make print-X prints value of variable X
print-%: ; @echo $* = $($*)

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo "make <all|clean>"

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
    @echo "compilation done"

$(OBJS) : $(SRCS)  $(BUILDDIR)/.create
    @echo "\"compiling\" $< to produce $@"
    cp $< $@

$(BUILDDIR)/.create:
    @echo "creating sandbox"
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR) && cd  $(BUILDDIR)
    @touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "deleting sandbox"
    @rm  -rf $(BUILDDIR)
```

If I type make all, the file works as expected.  However, if I type make all again, instead of saying everything is up to data, I end up with the following contents in the sandbox:

o.file1.src  o.file2.src  o.file3.src  o.file4.src  o.file5.src  o.o.file1.src  o.o.file2.src  o.o.file3.src  o.o.file4.src  o.o.file5.src

And the process of creating objects of objects continues recursively as many times as I type make.

Any help would be appreciated.

Incidentally, please don't post solutions that rely on the build in compile functions of make.  I'm looking for a general solution that can be used for any task.  For example, in this instance, I'm trying to read the source files into a tool using its command line interface.

Comment: You should certainly quote the asterisk in `find ... -name *.src` to avoid surprises in the presence of foo.src.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, by having your sandbox as a subdirectory of your source directory, then using `find` on the source directory, every time you run it you're going to find all the files in both the source directory and all its subdirectories, including the sandbox.  If the built files in the sandbox have the same names as the files in the source directories, the `find` will find them all.

Maybe instead of:

```
SRCS     := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.src)
```

you want something like:

```
SRCS     := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name $(notdir $(BUILDDIR)) -prune -o -name *.src -print)
```

Or, alternatively, don't make your sandbox a subdirectory of your source directory.  Or, make sure that whatever name you give to the files in the sandbox directory won't match the `*.src` pattern you give to `find`.

But beyond that this is wrong:

```
$(OBJS) : $(SRCS)  $(BUILDDIR)/.create
```

Suppose `SRCS` is `foo.src bar.src`, which means `OBJS` is `sandbox/o.foo.src sandbox/o.bar.src`.  Then the above expands to this:

```
sandbox/o.foo.src sandbox/o.bar.src : foo.src bar.src sandbox/.create
```

This is a common mistake; people seem to think that make will go through the targets and prerequisites and match them up, so the first target depends on the first prerequisite and the second target depends on the second one etc. but of course this cannot work correctly and that's not how make works.  Make treats the above as if you'd written one rule for each target, with the same prerequisites; like this:

```
sandbox/o.foo.src : foo.src bar.src sandbox/.create

sandbox/o.bar.src : foo.src bar.src sandbox/.create
```

You can see this won't do what you want at all, since the `$<` will always be `foo.src` which is clearly wrong.

You need to write a single pattern rule that will build ONE target.  Then make sure the pattern applies to all the targets.

You have made things hard for yourself by trying to "flatten" a directory structure of multiple source subdirectories, into a single level of target directory (by using the `$(notdir $(SRCS))`).  Because of this, there's no pattern that will match the same target and directory, unless you write a separate rule for every subdirectory.

Luckily there is a solution for this: `VPATH`.  This should work for you:

```
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SRCS))

$(BUILDDIR)/o.%.src : %.src  $(BUILDDIR)/.create
        @echo "\"compiling\" $< to produce $@"
        cp $< $@
```

The `VPATH` tells make to go look in all the directories that it found any sources in, whenever it can't find one to build.

Comment: I realized I'd goofed about the recursion as soon as I posted the question.  Sorry about that; I created the test case without enough checking.  However, you got to the nub of my problem all the same.  Because I had tried all sorts of pattern matching combinations as well but never got something that worked properly, mostly as you rightly said, because I didn't understand how make works.  Many thanks for explaining my misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your `SRCS` is all files in all subdirectories that match the pattern *.src (when you run make).  That means that all your object files (`$(OBJS)`) also match, so they copied as well.

The solution is to change your SRCS pattern so it does not match the "object" files in the build directory.  Possibilities:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.src)
```

or

```
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name $(notdir $(BUILDDIR)) -prune -false -o -name *.src)
```

or change the names of your "object" files so they don't end in `.src`

Answer (score 0):

> If I type make all, the file works as expected.

By which I take you to mean that directory `./sandbox` exists and contains these files:

```
o.file1.src
o.file2.src
o.file3.src
o.file4.src
o.file5.src
```

> However, if I type make all again, instead of saying everything is up to data, I end up with the following contents in the sandbox:
>
> o.file1.src o.file2.src o.file3.src o.file4.src o.file5.src o.o.file1.src o.o.file2.src o.o.file3.src o.o.file4.src o.o.file5.src

Of course you do, because everything is *not* up to date at that point, according to the target list you create.  This line ...

> ```
> SRCS     := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.src)
> ```

... defines `SRCS` as a list of all the files under path `./` (which is the value of `SRC_DIRS`) that ends in `.src`.  That includes any such files in `./sandbox`, which include all the files placed there by the first `make` run.  You generate a corresponding target file to build for each source, and those targets corresponding to sources built by the previous `make` run will not, in general, exist yet.  So `make` builds them, just as you instructed it.

The best solution, short of abandoning that automatic source identification altogether, would probably be to change your naming scheme so that outputs cannot be mistaken so easily for sources.  For example, if you want the output names to have the form `foo.src`, then have the corresponding input named something like `foo.src.in`.  In that particular case, you could convert from source names to target names with

```
OBJS     := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/o., $(basename $(notdir $(SRCS) ) ) )
```

Alternatively, you could modify the `find` command to skip the sandbox directory, maybe by modifying `SRC_DIRS`:

```
SRC_DIRS = src1 src2 subfolder/src3
```

(These specific alternatives are not mutually exclusive.)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply John. Yes I could change the names of my objects although, in fact, what I want is not a o. prefix but a . prefix.  Because I want the objects to be hidden; they are only there to record the fact that I have done the real task (which is actually to read all my SystemVerilog files into Quartus).  I could cut the .src file extension off as well I guess to remove the confusion.